Spyder 5.5.3 can't locate the kernels
So I just use Spyder version 5.5.3 with custom python interpreter which is 3.12.3 but the IPython says
The Python environment or installation whose interpreter is located at
C:\Program Files\Python312\python.exe
doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it installed (>= 2.5.0 and < 2.6.0). Without this module is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you.
You can install it by activating your environment first (if necessary) and then running in a system terminal:
conda install spyder-kernels=2.5
or
pip install spyder-kernels==2.5.*
I've installed the kernel using "pip install spyder-kernels==2.5.*" but nothing changed
I've restart the app over and over, then uninstall and reinstalling the app again and again but nothing happened.
Does anyone have the way to resolve this? Since I checked everything are in the latest updates
Thank you very much.

for clarity, do you mean that you tried this to install "Jupyter kernels for the Spyder console" ?  ie. this:  https://pypi.org/project/spyder-kernels

It's possible to have multiple Python installations in different places on your system, are you sure that your pip command installed for the correct one? Did you type that pip command at a plain Windows command prompt, or somewhere else? What do you get if you do where pip at the same prompt?
